# AuthType not set; MAMP 500 configuration error: couldn't perform authentication

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mamp

When I go to `localhost` I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Upon checking */Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log*

I get this error:

```
[Fri Sep 28 12:21:31 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Sep 28 12:21:31 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Sep 28 12:21:31 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 48678)
[Fri Sep 28 12:21:31 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.8 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 28 12:21:34 2018] [crit] [client ::1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /, referer: http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English
```

This is my **.htaccess** file

```
# Web fonts
AddType application/font-woff                       woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

# Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
# however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
# following fonts.
AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
AddType font/opentype                               otf

# Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
# https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml                           svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                                    svgz

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /restage/
Options +Indexes

DirectoryIndex rootfile.php

RewriteRule en/home$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule de/home$ /de/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/home$ /nl/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/home$ /ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/home$ /hu/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/home$ /pt/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule de$ /de/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^perfumes.christinaaguilera.com$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://perfumes.christinaaguilera.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !microsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)v_([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /restage/$3 [L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^137.177.80.74$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_media.txt [L]

RewriteRule hu/$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/awards$ /en/awards [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/buynow$ /en/buynow [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/bynight$ /en/bynight [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/redsin$ /en/redsin [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/royaldesire$ /en/royaldesire [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/signature$ /en/signature [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/sitemap$ /en/sitemap [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/unforgettable$ /en/unforgettable [R=301,L]
RewriteRule hu/woman$ /en/woman [R=301,L]

RewriteRule nl/$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/awards$ /en/awards [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/buynow$ /en/buynow [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/bynight$ /en/bynight [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/redsin$ /en/redsin [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/royaldesire$ /en/royaldesire [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/signature$ /en/signature [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/sitemap$ /en/sitemap [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/unforgettable$ /en/unforgettable [R=301,L]
RewriteRule nl/woman$ /en/woman [R=301,L]

RewriteRule pt/$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/awards$ /en/awards [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/buynow$ /en/buynow [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/bynight$ /en/bynight [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/redsin$ /en/redsin [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/royaldesire$ /en/royaldesire [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/signature$ /en/signature [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/sitemap$ /en/sitemap [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/unforgettable$ /en/unforgettable [R=301,L]
RewriteRule pt/woman$ /en/woman [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ru/$ /en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/awards$ /en/awards [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/buynow$ /en/buynow [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/bynight$ /en/bynight [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/redsin$ /en/redsin [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/royaldesire$ /en/royaldesire [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/signature$ /en/signature [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/sitemap$ /en/sitemap [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/unforgettable$ /en/unforgettable [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ru/woman$ /en/woman [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) rootfile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rootfile.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rootfile.php/$1 [L]
```

This is my **httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
# Virtual Hosts

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev"
    ServerName fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc
    ServerAlias www.fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE 09.28.18**

msg suggested some changes in my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
# Virtual Hosts

# NameVirtualHost *:80

# <VirtualHost *:80>
#   ServerName localhost
#   DocumentRoot /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__
#   # <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/">
#   #   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
#   #   AllowOverride All
#   #   Order Deny, Allow
#   #   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#   # </Directory>
# </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev"
    ServerName fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc
    ServerAlias www.fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny, Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my **http.conf** file:

```
#
ServerRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library"

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware.c>
PidFile logs/httpd.pid
</IfModule>

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule xsendfile_module modules/mod_xsendfile.so

LoadModule php7_module        /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/modules/libphp7.so

#
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User antonio-pavicevac-ortiz
Group #-1

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule xsendfile_module>
    XSendFile on
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin you@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
# MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT !! Don't remove this line !!
DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options All

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    XSendFilePath "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/__work__"
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <IfModule perl_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.pl
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule wsgi_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.wsgi index.py
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<Files ~ "^\.DS_Store">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel error

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_access.log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.
    #
    # We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If you
    # do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
    #

    Alias /favicon.ico "/Applications/MAMP/bin/favicon.ico"

    Alias /icons/ "/Applications/MAMP/Library/icons/"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/Library/icons">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /phpMyAdmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin"
    Alias /phpmyadmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /phpPgAdmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpPgAdmin"
    Alias /phppgadmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpPgAdmin"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpPgAdmin">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /phpLiteAdmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpLiteAdmin"
    Alias /phpliteadmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpLiteAdmin"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpLiteAdmin">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /MAMP "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /adminer "/Applications/MAMP/bin/adminer"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/adminer">
        DirectoryIndex adminer.php
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/"

    Alias /perl/ "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/"

    <IfModule perl_module>
        PerlModule ModPerl::Registry
        <Location /perl>
            SetHandler perl-script
            PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
            PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
            Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/ directory can be
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 1024
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 1024

#
# Uncomment the next line if Apache should not accept SSLv3 connections, to learn more google for "POODLE SSLv3".
# SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
</IfModule>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `Require local` as [that's for apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) while you are using 2.2, and `Require` [triggers authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require).

If you need to [restrict access based on ip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html), use:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

If you don't need any access control, just use

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually updated my question to reflect your suggestion. Is the syntax right?

Comment: I'm getting `Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.`

Comment: Running `apachectl configtest` yields: Syntax OK

Comment: You mentioned several `Allow` directives in `httpd.conf`; I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: Try removing the two new lines from the `<Directory>` in your first VHost, you already have them in `httpd.conf` maybe they are conflicting

Comment: I updated the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file above! Is that right? Now when I get localhost I do get all my projects appearing under `localhost`, however when I go to the site in question I get: `Not Found
The requested URL /www.fragrances.christinaaguilera.loc/en/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz could you try commenting the whole first VHost ? It declares the same `ServerName` as your main config

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting `Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration` again.  I updated the code in the vhosts section above to be sure I'm following you correctly.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz about the not found, that looks like another problem altogether related to the `RewriteRule`s in your `.htaccess` since now don't match `/rootfile.php`. But you said "accessing `localhost`", that's defined as another vhost (And the directory structure don't seem to match with your directives).

Comment: I give up, for now. But thanks so much for your help!